# Total installed system memory - cross-platform solution

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm writing a C# program, and one of the requirements I must fulfill is determining the total installed system memory for determining values for a config file. This isn't an XY problem, this information is mandatory.

Before I made this cross-platform, I could use the `ComputerInfo` class in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices` namespace, but this is not available in .NET Core, so I cannot use it on a non-Windows platform. The `System.Diagnostics.Process` class provides information on the memory available to the current process, but this does not include the total physical RAM available on the machine.

Is there a cross-platform way of querying this, or do I have to resort to having the user input this information manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `.NET Core` is a cross-platform framework, I suspect that developers are still figuring out how to implement a solid system capable of collecting hardware information from different operating system and from a wide variety of hardware products.

It seems that you are not the first person attempting to achieve this task:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22660

I think that you have to accomplish this through a tricky (and probably underperforming) workaround. I propose you one: use `Process.Start` (from `System.Diagnostics` library) in order to execute OS-specific commands (based on the current application environment) that are capable of providing the information you are looking for.

For example, for `Linux` you could use one of the following commands (depending on the format you want your output to have):

```
dmidecode -t 17 | grep  Size:
awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo
```

for `MacOS` one of the following commands:

```
hwprefs memory_size
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep "  Memory:"
```

and so on...

I know it's bad, but I think it's still better than forcing your users to manually enter the value.

Comment: Thanks for the commands! I think that will work for my use case; it shouldn't be terribly difficult to abstract out the correct commands based on platform. Hopefully at some point, Microsoft will implement platform-dependent native calls and make a standard API for acquiring this information, but for now this will work.